# Parallel Cholesky decomposition in PyTorch GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, linear-algebra, lapack

To get a differentiable term containing the determinant of a `D`-dimensional positive-definite matrix `C` (differential entropy of a multivariate Gaussian in my case), I can use:

```
torch.log2(torch.potrf(C).diag()).sum() + D / 2.0 * (np.log2(2 * np.pi * np.e))
```

`potrf(C)` performs Cholesky decomposition, whose diagonal elements' log values sum to the log determinant divided by 2.

I want to call `potrf` on a mini-batch of matrices, so that calling `potrf` on a Tensor of shape `(N, D, D)` produces `N` different Cholesky decompositions.

At the moment I can only call `potrf()` repeatedly in a Python loop, which is a poor use of the GPU's parallel compute capability and as a result runs about 3 times slower than CPU.

Is it possible to launch Cholesky decomposition on GPU in parallel with PyTorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Batch Cholesky decomposition is now available in PyTorch.***

Along with batch inverse(), etc.

---

---

***For older versions of Pytorch***

You are looking for Batch Cholesky decomposition. It's not implemented in Pytorch at the moment, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7500) and plan to add it in the future.

I only know of a [Batch LU factorization](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.btrifact) available in Pytorch 0.4. You could use it to get something similar:

```
det(D) = det(P)det(L)det(U)
```

where the determinant of P is `(-1)^t` and the determinants of P and U are the product of the diagonal elements.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, `btrifact` is not differentiable yet, and I think I have to resort to Python loops for now :(

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.8, PyTorch has native support for numpy-style [`torch.linalg`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.0/linalg.html) operations, including Cholesky decompositions:

```py
torch.linalg.cholesky(input)
```

> NOTE: When given inputs on a CUDA device, this function synchronizes that device with the CPU.